# Google Apps: Can I add a domain alias via the Google Admin API?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

The title says it all. I want to programmatically add [domain aliases](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53295?hl=en) via the [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/).

Comment: With current Admin sdk you cant programatically add domain aliases. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372841/programmatically-add-domain-alias-google-apps-api-php

Comment: OK, thanks. I was looking for an answer from a more credible source (e.g. someone from Google).

Answer (score 0):

You can manage DomainAliases including adding an alias through the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/) (Admin SDK) using the following post request (replacing 'myalias.com' and 'parentdomain.com' with your values; you will need to include your authorization token Authorization header).

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/domainaliases

Authorization: Bearer xxx-token-xxx
Content-Type: application/json

{
 "domainAliasName": "myalias.com",
 "parentDomainName": "parentdomain.com"
}
```

The [documentation for this API method](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/domainAliases/insert) includes the APIs Explorer providing a convenient form to test this API using OAuth to authenticate with your user. When completing the form on this page, enter 'my_customer' in the customer field.